# How to get a property from JSON in AngularJS with select form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am stuck AngularJS and JSON.
I have view called form.html that allow user can select their province.
I created Province JSON file and put in select tag, but when I store mySQL I need a province Id
I tried ng-value="province.id" in option tag but doesn't work. How can I get a pid(provinceId) at same time when user select province?

**province.JSON**

```
[
    {
    "pid" : 1,
    "name" : "Ontario"
    },
    {
    "pid" : 2,
    "name" : "Québec"
    },
    {
    "pid" : 3,
    "name" : "Nova Scotia"
    },
    {
    "pid" : 4,
    "name" : "New Brunswick"
    },
     ...
```

**form.html**

```
<select name="province" ng-model="user.province" ng-required="true"> 
 <option value="">--- Please select ---</option> 
 <option ng-repeat="province in provinces">{{province.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**controllers.js**

```
$scope.submitForm = function (user) {              
    dataObj = {
        "name": user.name,           //it works and all fine
        "province": user.province,   //it works and all fine
        "telephone": user.telephone, //it works and all fine
        "postalcode": user.postalcode, //it works and all fine
        "salary": user.salary,         //it works and all fine
        "provinceId" : user.pid       // undefine .. 
    }
```

Comment: And the PHP part is...?

Comment: `<option ng-repeat="province in provinces" ng-value="province.pid">{{province.name}}</option>` ?

Comment: Does PHP matter?  I think my php is okay

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work AJ

Comment: Try using `ng-options` instead `ng-repeat`.

Comment: try `<select required name="province" ng-model="user.province" ng-options="province.pid as province.name for province in provinces"></select>`

Comment: @Jason There's no PHP at all in your code.

Comment: @Rahul it doesn't work I tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.provinces = [{
                        "pid" : 1,
                        "name" : "Ontario"
                        },
                        {
                        "pid" : 2,
                        "name" : "Québec"
                        },
                        {
                        "pid" : 3,
                        "name" : "Nova Scotia"
                        },
                        {
                        "pid" : 4,
                        "name" : "New Brunswick"
                        }
                      ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <select name="contactCountry" ng-model="user.province" ng-options="item.pid as item.name for item in provinces" ><option value="">Select provinces</option>
 </select> 
 <br>
 <p>Selected Province Id = {{user.province}}</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!!.

Comment: thanks! it works but I need province.name as well to just display how can I get a province name at the same time?

Comment: thanks, It actually worked for me with editing some code I got a concept from you thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when user submit select tag will  be as object like {"pid:1", "name":"Ontario"} so I can fetch in my controller

The point is I should make as oject.

**html file**

```
 <select name="province" ng-model="user.province" ng-options="item.name for item in provinces" class="form-control input-lg" ng-required="true"> 
    <option value="">Select provinces</option>
 <select>
```

**controllers.js**

```
    myFactory.set(user);                 
    dataObj = {
        "name": user.name, 
        "province": user.province.name,   
        "telephone": user.telephone,
        "postalcode": user.postalcode, 
        "salary": user.salary,
        "pid" : user.province.pid
    }
```